# How to make JTable cells editable or non-Editable at Run time?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I am using a JTable and the parameters in table are passing through Hash Map.
Hash Map contains 2 parameters. 1 is key(String) & other one is Value(that is a Vector).
Vector contains the 2 things :First value(Corresponding to Key) and other one is a Character(R/W).(Read/Write).

I have make a table through this HashMap.But I am not able to use the"R/W" value at runtime.
If the paticular cell contains "R" It means that the particular cell is available only for Reading(non-Editable cell).
If the paticular cell contains "W" It means that the particular cell is available only for Write the new value also (Editable cell).

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
public class DataTable extends JTable implements ActionListener,ItemListener,MouseListener
{
String ReadOrWrite[][];
JTable table;
public DataTable()
{
    try
    {
        HashMap<String,String> HMap;
        String array[][];
        int count = 0;
        Vector Val;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        HMap = getMetaData();
        array = new String[HMap.size()][2];
        ReadOrWrite = new String[HMap.size()][2];
        for (Map.Entry entry : HMap.entrySet())
        {
            array[count][0] = (String) entry.getKey();
            Val = (Vector) entry.getValue();
            array[count][1] = (String) Val.elementAt(0);
            String s1 = (String) Val.elementAt(1);
            ReadOrWrite[count][1] = s1;
            count++;
        }
            String TableLabels[] = {"Field", "Values"};
            table = new JTable(array, TableLabels);
            table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
            {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
                {
                }
             }
            JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            panel.add(scrollPane);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setSize(300, 400);
            frame.setResizable(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
HashMap getMetaData()
{
    HashMap ta=new HashMap();

    Vector vec1 =new Vector();
    vec1.add("1");
    vec1.add("R");
    Vector vec2 =new Vector();
    vec2.add("2");
    vec2.add("W");
    ta.put("A",vec1);
    ta.put("B",vec2);
    return ta;
}
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
{
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}
```

}
This is the complete Code of my Table.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: PLZ look at the link, that is **NOT** an SSCCE.  Also, please make the effort to spell words fully.  (It is 'please', not 'plz')

Comment: *"i don't understand that how to create this SSCCE."*  What don't you understand?  Do you understand the words of the abbreviation?

Comment: I'm guessing that by 'post' you mean 'create', since the process of posting an SSCCE is exactly the same as posting code snippets.  And that leads me back to **What don't you understand about creating an SSCCE?**  Be specific rather than repeating that you don't know how.  That *won't* result in progress.

Comment: *"The whole code is write down above."* Where is `HashMap` imported?  What is the class name?  If it were 'the whole code', both those things would be obvious.  Do this test for me: 1) Start a new code project.  2) Copy/paste **exactly** what is in the question above, as the code. 3) Compile it.  4) report the errors. 5) Repeat that exact experiment with any of the [questions I've asked](http://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson) that contain code.  Those code samples **are** SSCCEs.

Comment: Try the experiment in my last comment, with your current code, to see..  `I:\...\DataTable.java:49: ')' expected`. An SSCCE of a run-time problem should compile without errors.  Why is it so hard to understand?

Comment: There is no error while i compile my code(New project)..So what i have to do next ?

Comment: I give up.  In the time you have been stuffing around, I have prompted other people to post an SSCCE.  They've posted an SSCCE.  I've corrected the problem and posted an answer.  They've seen the answer and marked it correct.  I don't have time to spoon-feed you any more.

Comment: Dear sir...Thanks For giving me response..I have given Complete code to you Sir.By this code a table will generated and By Default it is Editable...I just simply want to know that how can i make my table editable and non-editable at Run Time (With R/W values)......

Answer (score 3):

If you've implemented your own [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html), you can define the [isCellEditable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29) method to return `true` only when e.g. the second column equals `'W'`.

Comment: So where exactly are you storing the R/W? If they're not in the displayed table but they're in the data structure, you can still return true depending on the R/W for the current row, regardless of the column given as argument.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to how the hash map is passed to the table? If I remember, the default model uses a vector of vectors, so there's some conversion involved.

Answer (score 2):

In order to selectively make some of the cells in your [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) read-only, override the [isCellEditable()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29) method of your JTable and provide the desired logic in the implementation.

If you have a custom [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html), you can override [isCellEditable()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29) there instead.

In either case, your implementation of isCellEditable() should return `true` if and only if the cell specified by the row and column parameters contains 'W'.